# Arranging borderless MDI child forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

I have an MDI Parent form with potentially many children. So, I have the issue of the borders of the children taking up a lot of space. My solution is to give the user an easy to access option for removing the children form borders. This is easy with

```
child.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

The issue is that the whole point is form them to click "Tile Horizontal" and everything arranges nicely with more room than before. The only problem is that the borders disappear, with empty space where the border was, and when "Tile Horizontal" is clicked nothing happens. I am assuming this is because the Child forms are not resizable when their border is none.

Is there any way to do this without manually rearranging?

Comment: Have you looked into `Modal Forms` without borders?

Comment: Changing the border style on MDI child windows is not supported by MDI.  Winforms forgets to throw an exception.

Comment: @Greg, I didn't. I guess I don't understand what you are getting at. From what I understand, Modal Forms are very similar to dialogs, and I don't understand how that would help.

Comment: My thought process; is it would force "one form" up at a time to avoid your issues you were having.

Comment: But, I want to display 8 forms at a time and be able to switch back and forth.